# Joining two tables and find 10 maximum averages

Tags: mysql

I am developing a business review system.
`business` table is-

```
id     category
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
```

`review` table is -

```
id     bid     reviewer_point
1       1             4
2       1             3
3       2             4
4       2             5
```

I need to return the `10` `business ID`'s of the top rated (based on rating point average) business.

So far i could find the average of the rating of each business. 
`SELECT COUNT(reviewer_point) AS COUNT, AVG(reviewer_point) AS average FROM reviews WHERE bid = 1`
How can i get my preferred solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: why are u counting reviewer_point?

Comment: To get `how many` reviews has been done and `average` of them.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just order by the average descending and use a LIMIT clause

```
SELECT bid, AVG(reviewer_point) AS average 
FROM reviews 
GROUP BY bid
ORDER BY average DESC
LIMIT 10
```

EDIT - If you want to only do this for a specific category:-

```
SELECT reviews.bid, AVG(reviews.reviewer_point) AS average 
FROM reviews 
INNER JOIN categories
ON reviews.bid = categories.id
WHERE categories.category = 1
GROUP BY reviews.bid
ORDER BY average DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother again. uanble to filter by category id by WHERE clause. Can you please expand with where clause?

Comment: I have added a suggestion for filtering by category. Presume you mean the actual category (which can have multiple ids).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like category is needed in your solution, unless I'm missing something.

Its going to be something like:

```
SELECT bid, COUNT(*) as review_count, AVG(reviewer_point) as average_points
FROM reviews
GROUP BY bid
ORDER BY average_points DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Category is just for selecting them from a specific category which i can add with a `where` clause. Its working. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother again. uanble to filter by category id by WHERE clause. Can you please expand with where clause?